# Python array text sorting

Tags: python, parsing, text

For some context behind this project, I have a file with over 500 text documents that look like the following example:

```
Case: 44951651558
Sex: M
Age: 50

COLLECTED:  07/26/2019
REPORTED:  07/29/2019
SURGICAL PATHOLOGY REPORT
DIAGNOSIS

A.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
```

This is the structure of the txt files that I have. I have the task of taking these text files and assigning the given values to variables such as case, sex, age, collected, reported, and diagnosis. Here is the code that I currently have :

```
import os
directory = "E:\\Tubular Adenoma\\"

keywords = ["Case: ",
            "Sex: ",
            "Age: ",
            "COLLECTED: ",
            "REPORTED: ",
            "DIAGNOSIS"]

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        lines = []
        with open(directory + filename, "rt") as file:
            for line in file:
                lines.append(line)
            print(lines)

    else:
        continue
```

I am attempting to assign the values in the text files to keywords as given in the keywords array. I believe that this is going to be a dead-end and there is probably an easier way to do this. Anything helps.

The desired output is an array that contains the elements listed in the keywords array. For example, in the example project the array would look like the following:

```
["44951651558", "M", "50", "07/26/2019", "07/29/2019", "A.  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod..."]
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do, you mention the input, but not the output, the end result, where do you want which exact into to end up in what type; You can read all the files and parse them in a data structure, from where then to manipulate and manage the information

Comment: @Petronella My apologies, it is quite late and I did miss that, the desired output is an array with the case number, age, sex, collected, reported, and diagnosis. I need the output to be an array because I am going to convert the data into an excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work with other files and it will now return a list of lists.

```
import os
directory = "E:\\Tubular Adenoma\\"

# changed keywords list to dictionary to store the total characters to remove
# when applying slices on line #21
keywords = {'Case:': 6, 'Sex:': 5, 'Age:': 5, 'COLLECTED:': 12, \
    'REPORTED:': 11}

entities = []

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        lines = []
        with open(directory + filename, "rt") as file:
            for line in file:
                # added .strip() to remove all \n after lines
                lines.append(line.strip())

        # Added a list to store all the values
        info = []

        for l in lines:
            for k, v in keywords.items():
                if l.find(k) == 0:
                    info.append(l[v:])

        diagnoses = ''

        # Gets index of DIAGNOSIS and adds 2 to remove the empty line
        slice_value = lines.index("DIAGNOSIS") + 2

        # Loops over every line after DIAGNOSIS in the lines list and appends them to
        # a string called diagnoses.
        for l in lines[slice_value:]:
            diagnoses += l

        info.append(diagnoses)
        entities.append(info)

for e in entities:
    print(e)
```

Comment: So the desired output is an array as listed in the example, I am currently deconstructing your code and pulling parts from it into a test script I am running. If you find a way to match the desired output on a file to file basis (so the output looks like the following:
['123456789', 'F', '67', '02/20/2019', '02/22/2019'],
['123456789', 'M', '85', '02/21/2019', '02/25/2019'],

This is the desired output for every file in my folder. But thank you for the help nonetheless.

Comment: I made some changes that will allow the code to run properly with multiple files, it will now store each list in a master list